# In memory activemq not persisting across connections

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I need help understanding something about ActiveMQ.

```
    connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
```

Scenario #1 - I create a connection, close it, open a new connection and then try to retrieve a message off the queue. This results is not finding a message.

```
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();
    Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Queue queue = session.createQueue(CRIMS_REQUEST_QUEUE);

    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
    producer.send(session.createTextMessage(message));
    session.commit();

    connection.stop();
    connection.close();



    Connection connection2 = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection2.start();
    Session session2 = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Queue queue2 = session2.createQueue(CRIMS_REQUEST_QUEUE);
    MessageConsumer consumer2 = session2.createConsumer(queue2);
    TextMessage msg2 = (TextMessage)consumer2.receive(1000);
    System.out.println("The msg");
    System.out.println(msg2.getText());
    connection.close();
```

Scenario #2 - I use the same connection to create a new session, and it works just fine

```
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Queue queue = session.createQueue(CRIMS_REQUEST_QUEUE);

        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
        producer.send(session.createTextMessage(message));
        session.commit();

//      connection.stop();
//      connection.close();



//      Connection connection2 = connectionFactory.createConnection();
//      connection2.start();
        Session session2 = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Queue queue2 = session2.createQueue(CRIMS_REQUEST_QUEUE);
        MessageConsumer consumer2 = session2.createConsumer(queue2);
        TextMessage msg2 = (TextMessage)consumer2.receive(1000);
        System.out.println("The msg");
        System.out.println(msg2.getText());
        connection.close();
```

What's going on is, I have this code setting up a test case (hence the in memory queue) and I want to be able to stage a message in the queue in the test and then access in the real code (passing the connection factory from one to the other). Should I be passing the connection instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the expected behavior. The URL you're using (i.e. `vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false`) actually *creates and starts* an embedded broker (with persistence disabled mind you) when the first connection is made. Once that connection is closed the broker also disappears.

Therefore, you should pass the connection rather than the connection factory. Or you could manage the broker instance independently.

Read more about this in the [ActiveMQ documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection) (scroll down to the "Using ActiveMQConnectionFactory" section).